# Should I not include a user's name when they help on an answer I gave?

Tags: support

I'm still learning proper etiquette, and I'm not sure how to handle this.

Recently I gave an answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159497/how-i-check-if-the-radius-is-greater-or-and-equal-to-0/159505#159505), and a couple of people gave some extra information as comments to my answer. In order to make my answer more complete, I added their suggestions to it, and also included their username, like `Edit: (thanks to @username)`, because I thought it was the proper thing to do.

Today my answer was edited to remove those lines.

I understand that those lines do not contribute to the answer, so they "shouldn't" be there, but on the other hand, it would seem unfair to just add them to my answer without mentioning who helped, as it would seem like it's my sayings.

Should I not include these lines in the future? Should I include people's suggestions from comments if I think it will improve my answer?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think it's a good practice to give credits for feedbacks in comments. In addition to mentioning the commenter, I usually also add the direct link to the comment.

However, comments are also 2nd-class citizen, or in other words, [temporary "Post-It" notes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Looking at the current state of your answer, it's clean from comments. Meaning that the mods have deleted them rightfully since you have incorporated them on your post. However, assume if your revision was used instead, it might be confusing (though probably understandable) why you thanked them on the post without any references since the comments have been deleted.

---

So, to answer the questions:

> Should I not include these lines in the future?

You could include it, but when it's removed, assume the comment has done its purpose.

> Should I include people's suggestions from comments if I think it will improve my answer?

**Yes, you should**. That's the main purpose they comment on your post.

---

Also, consider [not adding "Edit:" on the post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post) Future readers don't need to know if the post is edited or not. If they want to know, all edits are recorded on the revision history.

Comment: Thanks for the link about why "Edit:" is not the best idea! So would the best solution be to improve my answer based on comments, and maybe on the bottom of the answer insert something like "thanks to <user> and <user> for improving this answer" ?

Comment: I understand that you want to give them credits, but I don't think there's a good way to give them credit on the post for this particular case (this is my personal opinion, not mods or the community). Best case, you *already had given* them credits and the revision history shows it as a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up in meta!

I think it's great that you want to give other users credit for the improvement done to your answer, that's a good trait to have when working in great teams! As [Andrew T. explained in his answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2699/40264), the "Edit" part generally adds noise to the answer, and that's why I removed these parts from your answer.

> Should I not include a user's name when they help on an answer I gave?

Keep in mind that users here have the ability to change their username, so referring to users name (such as @JohnDoe) might be creating confusion for future readers. Linking to their profile, however, will make sure they receive the proper credit, as this will never change, even if they change their name. (This is a great suggestion from [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory), by the way ;p)

I edited the Answer you linked in the Question to reflect this, as we always like to experiment and improve the way we do things.

Comment: "Keep in mind that users here have the ability to change their username" Wow I did not know that, so it make sense to avoid using usernames on answers. Thanks a lot for the extra information!